# Use plurals with i18n-node

Tags: node.js, internationalization, handlebars.js, ejs

In my en.json file I have this:

```
{
    "house": {
        "one": "house",
        "other": "houses"
    }
}
```

But if I try this in EJS:

```
<%= __n('house', 3) %>
```

or this in Handlebars

```
{{{__n 'house' 3}}}
```

It always renders as "house", not "houses"

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: Probably not the best way to go about this... some languages have different plurals for masculine/feminine words.  Other languages have the concept of singular/dual/plural.

Comment: Yeah, I thought and decide to develop a package my own that supports different plurals and genders: https://github.com/talyssonoc/i18node